# Network Image doesn't change when it's URL is changed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I had created a Future function that would return a List of Strings containing the URLs of different images, what I wanted to do was to change the image whenever the user clicks on the current image, and therefore I wrote the following code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mangadex_library/chapter/ChapterData.dart';
import 'package:mangadex_library/mangadex_library.dart' as lib;
import 'package:mangadex_library/jsonSearchCommands.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class MangaReader extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChapterData chapterData;
  final String mangaId;
  final String token;
  final String chapterId;

  MangaReader(
      {required this.token,
      required this.chapterId,
      required this.mangaId,
      required this.chapterData});
  _MangaReaderState createState() => _MangaReaderState(
      globalToken: token,
      chapterId: chapterId,
      mangaId: mangaId,
      chapterData: chapterData);
}

class _MangaReaderState extends State<MangaReader> {
  final String globalToken;
  late String chapterId;
  final ChapterData chapterData;
  late String mangaId;

  _MangaReaderState(
      {required this.globalToken,
      required this.chapterId,
      required this.mangaId,
      required this.chapterData});
  JsonSearch jsonsearch = new JsonSearch();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool imgLoading = false;
    int chapterNumberTracker = 0;
    chapterId = chapterData.result[chapterNumberTracker].data.id;
    return new FutureBuilder(
      future: getAllFilePaths(chapterId, false),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>?> data) {
        if (data.hasData) {
          int pageIndex = 0;
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 75,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if (chapterNumberTracker != 0) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          chapterNumberTracker--;
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  child: Text('Chapter ' +
                                      (chapterNumberTracker + 1).toString()),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.skip_next,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        chapterNumberTracker++;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    child: imgLoading
                        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                        : InkWell(
                            child: Image(
                              image: NetworkImage(data.data![pageIndex]),
                            ),
                            onDoubleTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                if (pageIndex != 0) {
                                  imgLoading = true;

                                  pageIndex--;
                                  print(pageIndex);
                                  print(data.data![pageIndex]);
                                  imgLoading = false;
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(
                                () {
                                  if (data.data!.length != pageIndex + 1) {
                                    imgLoading = true;
                                    pageIndex++;
                                    print(pageIndex);
                                    print(data.data![pageIndex]);
                                    imgLoading = false;
                                  }
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future<List<String>?> getAllFilePaths(
      String chapterId, bool isDataSaverMode) async {
    var chapter = await lib.getChapters(mangaId);
    if (chapter != null) {
      var token = globalToken;
      if (token.isEmpty) {
        print('THERE IS NO TOKEN!');
      }
      var baseUrlClassInstance = await lib.getBaseUrl(chapterId);
      var baseUrl = baseUrlClassInstance!.baseUrl;
      var filenames =
          jsonsearch.getChapterFilenames(chapterId, chapter, isDataSaverMode);
      var urls = <String>[];
      var chapterData =
          jsonsearch.getChapterDataByChapterId(chapterId, chapter);
      var chapterHash = chapterData.data.attributes.hash;

      filenames.forEach(
        (v) {
          isDataSaverMode
              ? urls.add('$baseUrl/$token/data-saver/$chapterHash/$v')
              : urls.add('$baseUrl/$token/data/$chapterHash/$v');
        },
      );
      return urls;
    }
  }
}
```

I was using the 'pageIndex' variable to change in between the URLs in the list, but even if the URL changed, it still didn't update the image.

Comment: Does  your `Future` method get call on every onTap?

Comment: Show full code please

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I had used the FutureBuilder to get the data once and then use that in the  NetworkImage, but since the future builder gets all the URLs at once in the form of a list, I didn't think it was necessary for me to call Future on every tap.